# Shell Script from Objective c

Tags: objective-c, macos, shell

How can i run following command from objective using NSTask,

> pluginkit -e ignore -i com.xxxxx.Plugin_Id

I tried this but not worked,

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/sh"];
   [task setArguments: @[@"pluginkit",@"-e",@"ignore",@"-i",@"com.xxxxx.Plugin_Id"]];
    [task launch];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setLaunchPath` should be the binary you launching. `pluginkit` is located on `/usr/bin/`, so the launch code should be like this i think:

```c
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/pluginkit"];
[task setArguments: @[@"-e", @"ignore", @"-i", @"com.company.pluginId"]];
[task launch];
[task waitUntilExit];
```

or with a single lined call:

```c
system("pluginkit -e ignore -i com.company.pluginId");
```

Comment: I have some more issue in new version of  osx, can you help me for solution.

Comment: ask a new question, i will try my best, so as the others on this site

Comment: Sure, i had added a question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31268756/status-bar-window-not-showing).